# polymorphic association and creating a table for it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Say I have this:

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

Does this require me to define a table exactly in the following way?

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :pictures do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.integer :imageable_id
      t.string  :imageable_type
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :pictures, [:imageable_type, :imageable_id]
  end
end
```

Or may I define a bit differently, with different columns or types, for example, that is, in a way I see more efficient? Will the polymorphic association remain functioning?

Answer (score 0):

The polymorphic association only relates to the `_type` and `_id` pair of columns. Everything else is up to you.

So yes, you can add additional metadata if you like.